# Liftings and splittings (reference request)

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, homological-algebra

I'm writing a paper and, at a certain point, I need the following, rather elementary

**Lemma**. *Assume that we have a commutative diagram of short exact sequences of groups of the form*

[image]

*Then the liftings $\varphi \colon V' \to G$ of $\phi \colon V' \to V$ are in bijective correspondence to the splittings
$s \colon V' \to G'$ of the top sequence.*

One direction is clear: if $s \colon V' \to G'$ is a splitting of the top sequence, then $\varphi= \psi \circ s$ is a lifting of $\phi$. Conversely, a tedious but straightforward diagram chasing shows how to construct a splitting starting from a lifting.

Since the paper is quite long, I'm trying to shorten it and, in particular,  I would like not to present the standard proof of this result. On the other hand, I do not like those sentences of the form "The straightforward proof of the following easy statement is left to the reader", hence I'm looking for a reference.

I searched some textbooks of Group Theory and Homological Algebra, so far without success. However, my impression is that it should be somewhere, maybe buried in some exercise.

> **Question.** Where is it possible to find a proper reference to the above lemma?

Comment: In such a diagram the right square is cartesian. Maybe it is easier to find a reference of this fact (or you are willing to left this for the reader). Then the bijection is immediate.